# How do I save a large F# array of records to file?

Tags: f#

I want to save a large f# array of records (> 10,000,000 elements) to disk so that it is easy to reload the array into memory later. I used the following simple function from Visual F# 2010 for technical computing:

```
let save filename x =
    use stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create)
    BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, x)

type Test = { a : int; b : int}

let x = [| for i in 1..6 do 
            let a=i
            let b=i*i
            yield {a=a;b=b}|]

save "file.dat" x
```

When I do this (with the real data) I get the error:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The internal array cannot expand to greater than Int32.MaxValue elements.
```

Right now, my solution is to convert to Deedle and then save as a csv, but I presume that there is a more computationally efficient option for saving/reloading that does not require rebuilding the array from csv.

```
let x2 = x |> Frame.ofRecords
x2.SaveCsv("file.csv")
```

Comment: I'd either generate CSV on my own, or perhaps try using FsPicker: http://nessos.github.io/FsPickler/

Comment: `Int32.MaxValue` is `2,147,483,647`, which is orders of magnitude bigger than `10,000,000`, so I wonder what's really going wrong here...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Perhaps I stated the size wrong--I'm basing this on x.Length. Does it matter that the records have type `type rp = {a:int;b:int;c:LocalDate;d:LocalDate;c:float;d:float}`? The array is `val rp : rp []`. I assumed these details about the type of the record are irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing 10,000,000 lines to a text file isn't a problem. Here's a simple demo:

```
> let lines = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> sprintf "%i, %i, -%i" i (i * 2) i);;

val lines : seq<string>

> open System.IO;;
> #time;;

--> Timing now on

> File.WriteAllLines(@"test.csv", lines |> Seq.take 10000000);;
Real: 00:00:20.420, CPU: 00:00:20.343, GC gen0: 3528, gen1: 3, gen2: 1
val it : unit = ()
```

As you can see, that takes a mere 20 seconds.

Reading the lines back isn't too bad either:

```
> let roundTripped = File.ReadLines @"test.csv";;
Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

val roundTripped : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>
```

As you can see, this happens instantaneously, because `roundTripped` is loaded as a lazily evaluated sequence.

Still, it's possible to enumerate the values:

```
> roundTripped |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
```

(printout truncated for clarity; there are literally 10 million lines.)

```
...
9999997, 19999994, -9999997
9999998, 19999996, -9999998
9999999, 19999998, -9999999
Real: 00:03:43.995, CPU: 00:01:15.390, GC gen0: 594, gen1: 23, gen2: 3
val it : unit = ()
```

This takes a lot longer, but I suspect it's mainly because printing to the console tends to take time.

These experiments were made on my 3-year old Lenovo X1 Carbon - a fairly mainstream piece of hardware.

Thus, there's no problem with writing or reading millions of text lines, but do notice that I've avoided arrays in favour of lazily evaluated sequences.

---

Using records doesn't change the above conclusions. I wouldn't dare to design any sort of long-lasting persistence solution on .NET serialization (due to potential versioning issues), so I'd still convert to some other format for that purpose.

To stick with CSVs:

```
type Test = { A : int; B : int }

let records = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> { A = i; B = -i })
let csvs = records |> Seq.map (fun x -> sprintf "%i, %i" x.A x.B)
```

Records can be written and read in approximately the same times as reported above.

Comment: Can you change your answer to use records? I tried to make a simple edit to use the same code, but with records as in the question, but it was rejected. Will be helpful for new users searching for how to save an array of records to disk.

Comment: @nh2 Added a few paragraphs about records

Comment: Thanks for the point about versioning. I didn't know about that.

Comment: Minor note - you can use `Seq.iter ignore` if you want to measure accessing each element of the sequence without the overhead of printing.