# Efficiently read last row from a large csv file

Tags: csv, f#

Given a large csv file, is it possible to read the very last row in a reasonably efficient manner? I have the following python function that does this well. Wondering if there is an equivalent F# solution.

```
def readCsvLines(fp):
    with open(fp, "rb") as f:
        first = f.readline()
        second = f.readline()
        f.seek(-2, 2)              # jump to the second last byte
        while f.read(1) != "\n":   # until EOL is found...
            f.seek(-2, 1)          # jump back the read byte plus one more
        last = f.readline()
    return first, second, last
```

[EDIT]
I'm still unsure as to how to figure out to jump back just enough bytes to be on the second last line so that I can detect the end of line character and return the next line. The -100L might not be the correct amount to jump back depending on the csv (there are thousands).

```
open System.IO

let f = File.Open("someFile.txt", FileMode.Open)
f.Seek(-100L, SeekOrigin.End) |> ignore
let s = new StreamReader(f)

while s.Read() <> 10 do
    ignore

let ln = s.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Sure, you can seek in F# just fine. Look at `System.IO.File.Open`.

Comment: Related, with a potential answer embedded: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34227084/126014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work, assuming the file is ASCII or UTF-7, there's a single newline character to separate lines, and the file ends with a newline.

It's not really idiomatic F# though, quite imperative-style.

```
let lastLine (path) =
    use strm = new System.IO.FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 2048, FileOptions.RandomAccess)
    strm.Seek(-2L, SeekOrigin.End) |> ignore
    while (strm.ReadByte() <> 0xa) do
        strm.Seek(-2L, SeekOrigin.Current) |> ignore    

    use br = new BinaryReader(strm, System.Text.Encoding.UTF7)
    br.ReadChars(int (strm.Length - strm.Position) - 1) // Remove the newline at the end of the file  
    |> System.String
```