# CsvProvider throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: f#, f#-data

`FAOCropsLivestock.csv` contains more than 14 million row. In my `.fs` file I have declared

```
type FAO = CsvProvider<"c:\FAOCropsLivestock.csv">
```

and tried to work with follwoing code

```
FAO.GetSample().Rows.Where(fun x -> x.Country = country) |> ....
FAO.GetSample().Filter(fun x -> x.Country = country) |> ....
```

In both cases, `exception` was thrown.

I also have tried with follwoing code after loading the `csv` file in MSSQL Server

```
type Schema = SqlDataConnection<conStr>
let db = Schema.GetDataContext()
db.FAOCropsLivestock.Where(fun x-> x.Country = country) |> ....
```

it works. It also works if I issue `query` using `OleDb` connection, but it is slow.

How can I get a squence out of it using `CsvProvider`?

Comment: Have you tried creating a *small* `.csv` document with, for example, the first 100 lines of that big file? This should give the CSV provider something to work with without overwhelming it. I don't know if it'll work, but it might be able to parse the real file afterwards... Worth a try, I'd say....

Comment: @MarkSeemann `CsvProvider` has `Skip` and `Take` functions to do so ... But it probably will take more time than that of `OleDb`.

Comment: Every time you try to compile your code, a type provider will load in the sample document and attempt to infer types from it. If the sample document has 14 million rows, it may not be surprising that it runs out of memory. If you give it a small sample, it may actually be able to do its job.

Comment: At run-time, you can use `skip` and `take` if you need to, if the parser is able to read the file lazily at run-time... I don't know if it can, but otherwise, CSV files are fairly easy to parse by hand.

Comment: See for example this answer that writes and reads 10 million lines to a text file using basic F# IO functionality http://stackoverflow.com/a/34229014/126014

Comment: I will apply your technique in F#. I used `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`  in C# earlier for flat files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you refer to the bottom of the [CSV Type Provider documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html), you will see a section on handling large datasets.  As explained there, you can set `CacheRows = false` which will aid you when it comes to handling large datasets.

```
type FAO = CsvProvider<"c:\FAOCropsLivestock.csv", CacheRows = false>
```

You can then use standard sequence operations over the rows of the CSV as a sequence without loading the entire file into memory.  e.g.

```
FAO.GetSample().Rows |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.Country = country) |> ....
```

You should, however, take care to only enumerate the contents once.

Comment: It is 3 times slower than `OleDb` with a test for `DBNull.Value` for every column. It does not matter how much slower it is! it works fine with lesser code .... Thanks.